# get drupal instant changes for android service

Tags: services

i m building services for android in which i wanna achieve something like following,

=> when user is added/deleted/updated i need to send push notification on android device saying user has been added or whatever... is there any module or method available in drupal 7 by which i can get the latest changes..

=> wanna achieve same as above for node, comments....

plz help ...

Comment: What have you already tried? Did you search google? Searching google lists a push notifications module for drupal. http://bit.ly/W7V2Co

Comment: i have studied push notification module ...i got to send custom notifications through push notification... as mentioned above like user updates , comments etc...